# Вычисление значения математического выражения (обучающий пример)

Tags: c#

Есть такой калькулятор, как можно этот код уменьшить, также поставить валидацию?

```cs
class Logic
{
    static public double Calculate(string input)
    {

        {
            string output = GetExpression(input);
            double result = Counting(output);
            return result;
        }
    }


    static private string GetExpression(string input)
    {
        {
            string output = string.Empty;
            Stack<char> operStack = new Stack<char>();

            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {

                if (IsDelimeter(input[i]))
                    continue;


                if (Char.IsDigit(input[i]))
                {

                    while (!IsDelimeter(input[i]) && !IsOperator(input[i]))
                    {
                        output += input[i];
                        i++;

                        if (i == input.Length) break;
                    }

                    output += " ";
                    i--;
                }


                if (IsOperator(input[i]))
                {
                    if (input[i] == '(')
                        operStack.Push(input[i]);
                    else if (input[i] == ')')
                    {

                        char s = operStack.Pop();

                        while (s != '(')
                        {
                            output += s.ToString() + ' ';
                            s = operStack.Pop();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (operStack.Count > 0)
                            if (GetPriority(input[i]) <= GetPriority(operStack.Peek()))
                                output += operStack.Pop().ToString() + " ";

                        operStack.Push(char.Parse(input[i].ToString()));

                    }
                }
            }


            while (operStack.Count > 0)
                output += operStack.Pop() + " ";

            return output;
        }
    }


    static private double Counting(string input)
    {
        {
            double result = 0; //Результат
            Stack<double> temp = new Stack<double>();

            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {

                if (Char.IsDigit(input[i]))
                {
                    string a = string.Empty;

                    while (!IsDelimeter(input[i]) && !IsOperator(input[i]))
                    {
                        a += input[i];
                        i++;
                        if (i == input.Length) break;
                    }
                    temp.Push(double.Parse(a));
                    i--;
                }
                else if (IsOperator(input[i]))
                {

                    double a = temp.Pop();
                    double b = temp.Pop();

                    switch (input[i])
                    {
                        case '+': result = b + a; break;
                        case '-': result = b - a; break;
                        case '*': result = b * a; break;
                        case '/': result = b / a; break;
                        case '^': result = double.Parse(Math.Pow(double.Parse(b.ToString()), double.Parse(a.ToString())).ToString()); break;
                    }
                    temp.Push(result);
                }
            }
            return temp.Peek();
        }
    }
    static private bool IsDelimeter(char c)
    {
        if ((" =".IndexOf(c) != -1))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    static private bool IsOperator(char с)
    {
        if (("+-/*^()".IndexOf(с) != -1))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    static private byte GetPriority(char s)
    {
        switch (s)
        {
            case '(': return 0;
            case ')': return 1;
            case '+': return 2;
            case '-': return 3;
            case '*': return 4;
            case '/': return 4;
            case '^': return 5;
            default: return 6;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите выражение: ");
            string text = Console.ReadLine();
            if (text.Length == 0) break;
            Console.WriteLine(Logic.Calculate(text));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как этот класс предполагается использовать. Вы можете добавить больше деталей, зачем это сделано, и как используется? Так же приведите примеры входных и выходных данных.

Comment: Это стек калькулятор в где можно добавить скобки, возводить в степен в коде есть приоритет знаков, например 2+4*(8*4).Дальше это все я инициализирую в мейне

Comment: Мне шас нужно как-то уменьшить код, а также поставить валидацию что бы нельзя было вводить другие знаки а также буквы

Comment: Тег `инспекция кода` не подразумевает доработку или изменение логики работы вашего кода. Но сократить некоторые моменты можно, да.

Comment: Этот тег не я добавлял модератор отредактировал мой вопрос если вам не сложно можете показать как это можно сделать и если не сложно помогите с валидацией

Comment: Начните с того, что код работает не всегда правильно `2^2*2^2+3*4` я ожидаю ответ `28`, получаю `64`. Я уберу сейчас тег `инспекция кода` и отформатирую сам код.

Comment: хорошо спасибо я просто тока начал изучать C# мне покамись как-то трудно дается

Comment: Там логика кода такая что калькулятор с скобками также с степенью по идеи код должен сначала считать то что в скобках а потом идти дальше по приоритету

Comment: Хорошо, разберитесь, почему неправильно считает. Так же я дописал тестовый пример, чтобы можно было покинуть цикл, а то он был бесконечный.

Comment: Вы можете в обьеснить в чем проблема в коде или же показать я так понял вы добавили валидацию на пустую строку ?

Comment: Это же очевидно, что если строка пустая, то просто покинуть цикл. Это для удобства, чтобы насильно не прерывать работу программы. Вопрос: вы это с какой-то конкретной целью пишете, или чисто для самообучения?

Comment: Чисто для самообучение конкретной цели нету я учусь сморю онлайн уроки а также прохожу курсы в Степике

Comment: В остальном код нормальный ничего не надо изменять?

Comment: Мне сложно судить, с одной стороны я бы часть методов оптимизировал, с другой - написал бы все совсем по-другому, с третьей - ваш код не работает для сложных выражений, как приведенный мной пример выше. Я сейчас пытаюсь реализовать то, что вы сделали с нуля, и уже сделал без поддержки скобок, получилось интересно. Со скобками разберусь и выложу в ответ, с ними много разных вариантов можно реализовать, ищу самый простой. Вы нашли ошибку?

Comment: Честно говоря нет не нашел я запустил код вводил данные с скобками он нормально работал ну вот когда вводил буквы давал ошибку и плюс при пустом значение тоже выбивает ошибку

Comment: Спасибо вам за то что взялись за решением моей задачи я вам очень благодарен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На гениальность не претендую, многое сделано "в лоб", но следующий код вроде-как работает без ошибок.

```csharp
public static class Calculator
{
    private const string numberChars = "01234567890.";
    private const string operatorChars = "^*/+-";

    public static double Calculate(string expression)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(expression))
            throw new ArgumentException("Пустое выражение недопустимо", nameof(expression));

        CheckParenthesis(expression);

        return EvaluateParenthesis(expression);
    }

    private static double EvaluateParenthesis(string expression)
    {
        string planarExpression = expression;
        while (planarExpression.Contains('('))
        {
            int clauseStart = planarExpression.IndexOf('(') + 1;
            int clauseEnd = IndexOfRightParenthesis(planarExpression, clauseStart);
            string clause = planarExpression.Substring(clauseStart, clauseEnd - clauseStart);
            planarExpression = planarExpression.Replace("(" + clause + ")", EvaluateParenthesis(clause).ToString());
        }
        return Evaluate(planarExpression);
    }

    private static int IndexOfRightParenthesis(string expression, int start)
    {
        int c = 1;
        for (int i = start; i < expression.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (expression[i])
            {
                case '(': c++; break;
                case ')': c--; break;
            }
            if (c == 0) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private static void CheckParenthesis(string expression)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (char c in expression)
        {
            switch (c)
            {
                case '(': i++; break;
                case ')': i--; break;
            }
            if (i < 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("Не хватает '('", nameof(expression));
        }
        if (i > 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Не хватает ')'", nameof(expression));
    }

    private static double Evaluate(string expression)
    {
        string normalExpression = expression.Replace(" ", "");
        List<char> operators = normalExpression.Split(numberChars.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x[0]).ToList();
        List<double> numbers = normalExpression.Split(operatorChars.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => double.Parse(x)).ToList();

        if (operators.Count + 1 != numbers.Count)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Неверный синтаксис в выражении '{expression}'", nameof(expression));

        foreach (char o in operatorChars)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < operators.Count; i++)
            {
                if (operators[i] == o)
                {
                    double result = Calc(numbers[i], numbers[i + 1], o);
                    numbers[i] = result;
                    numbers.RemoveAt(i + 1);
                    operators.RemoveAt(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
        return numbers[0];
    }

    private static double Calc(double left, double right, char oper)
    {
        switch (oper)
        {
            case '+': return left + right;
            case '-': return left - right;
            case '*': return left * right;
            case '/': return left / right;
            case '^': return Math.Pow(left, right);
            default: throw new ArgumentException("Неподдерживаемый оператор", nameof(oper));
        }
    }
}
```

Вот так использовать

```csharp
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Чтобы дробные числа были с точкой, а не с запятой
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; 

    try
    {
        double result = Calculator.Calculate("2^2*2^(2+3)*4");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

И вот такой вывод в консоль

```
512
```

Я здесь не валидирую все подряд, можно в некоторых случаях бросать более вменяемые исключения, это просто обучающий пример, разберите его.

Comment: Извините ещё раз а как можно в ваш код добавить стек?

Comment: @VenDETTA зачем? Там используется стек вызовов в рекурсивном методе.

Comment: Ну просто задача была использовать стек для перебора чисел  Stack<char> operStack = new Stack<char>();  что-то такое

Comment: @VenDETTA к сожалению, я не знаю, куда здесь его засунуть, чтобы от него была польза. Думаю, он несовместим с этим решением. Можно конечно извратнуться и листы на стеки заменить, но станет только хуже. Я не думаю, что использование стека ради использования стека - это то что вам нужно. Подумайте, алгоритм простой, может найдете, как прикрутить.

Comment: хорошо спасибо большое

Comment: Это не работает: https://ideone.com/oASai5

Comment: @Qwertiy о, спасибо, пофикшено. :)

Comment: @VenDETTA в ответе исправлена ошибка.

Comment: Да, теперь работает: https://ideone.com/ZVnbkF. Хотя неэффективно (квадратичное решение вместо линейного) и унарные операторы в таком не реализовать.

Comment: @Qwertiy жаль, что решение получилось плохое, но я писал это сам, не по учебнику, без гугла, в обучающих целях, впервые в жизни. Что такое квадратичное, производительность? Не думаю, что юзер в консоли заметит разницу. Если бы мне нужно было эффективное решение, я бы использовал один из уже изобретенных велосипедов. :)

Comment: Вычисление выражений может быть реализовано с использованием записи выражений в постфиксной нотации. Там как раз стек выполняет ключевую роль в вычислении выражения. Я, правда, не знаю, насколько этот алгоритм вычисления выражений актуальный, но так мы в университете вычисляли выражения на лабораторных работах

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, там есть разные варианты. Но в любом случае тот алгоритм, который будет парсить обычную запись и переводить в постфиксную при желании может и посчитать сразу. Правда, это может быть несколько медленнее, но если выражение не содержит переменных и считается только один раз, то наоборот получится быстрее - выгода появляется если мы можем один раз распарсить выражение, а потом многократно считать. Ну и в самой обработке тоже можно приделать стек вместо рекурсии.