# string в string array

Tags: c#

Как перевести `string` в `string array`?

```
var string = 13+7-4/2+12

string[] secondString = {"13", "+", "7", "-", "4", "/", "2", "+", "12"};
```

Comment: А для чего вам разбитие? Я так понимаю, чтоб понять что делать с числами (складывать, вычитать и т.д.), верно? Почему бы просто не посчитать тогда? Например, для подсчета того, что у вас, можно просто написать `var result = (double)new DataTable().Compute("13+7-4/2+12", null);`, если будет что-то сложнее, то там надо скорей всего будет писать свой парсер. Касательно разбития строки, то просто напишите в поисковике `c# split math string` и получите нужно, но что вы будете делать, например если будет `1+2*(3/4)`, ну разобьете вы на `1,+,2,*,(,3,/,4,)`, а дальше? Продумайте все на перед!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, а дальше напишет алгоритм вычисления. Всё она правильно делает.

Comment: [Пример вычисления математического выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1174507/373567)

Comment: @Qwertiy для корректного вычисления, выражение надо перевести в нормальную форму, то есть числа и математические операторы должны быть скорее всего в разных массивах. Обратите внимание на метод `Evaluate(string expression)` по ссылке выше.

Comment: @aepot, нет, они не должны быть в разных массивах. Если они будут в разных массивах, то унарным операциям конец. Числа, скобки и операторы должны быть в одном массиве. Того же порядка, в каком они идут в строке, достаточно, чтобы вычислить значение. Но при желании можно переводить в другой формат.

Comment: @Qwertiy я отталкиваюсь от того, что дал выше по ссылке. Но реализации разные бывают, да

Comment: @aepot, по ссылке я детально не разбирал решение, но пример, на котором оно не работает, привёл. И в любом случае строка токенов удобнее, чем строка символов.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо за пойманный баг. Я исправил.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://ideone.com/mNsfqL

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var s = "13+7-4/2+12";
    string[] tokens = Regex.Matches(s, @"\d+|[-+/*()]").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", tokens));
  }
}
```