# Разбор строки с фукцией

Tags: c#

Имеется строка, в которой надо выделить функции и их входные данные.

Например, в строке `x<=count((a=1)||(a=2))+sum((x-t)*2)`, результатом вывода должен быть словарь, где ключ название функции, а значение ее входные данные.

Пробовал использовать регулярное выражение `(?<=((sum)|(count))\().*(?=\))`, но оно в результате дает выражение до последней скобки `(a=1)||(a=2))+sum((x-t)*2`. А должно быть `(a=1)||(a=2) и (x-t)*2`.

Думаю искать подстроку с названием функции во входной строке и с помощью стека парсить входные данные.

Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной задачей и имеет лучшее решение?

**upd**
Пришел к такому решению

```cs
private static IEnumerable<FunctionInfo> FindFunctions(string formula, List<Function> functions)
{
    formula = formula.Trim();
    var function = $"^({string.Join("|", functions)})";
    var regex = new Regex(function);
    while (formula.Length > 0)
    {
        var match = regex.Match(formula);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            formula = regex.Replace(formula, string.Empty, 1);

            Stack<char> brackets = new Stack<char>();
            brackets.Push(formula[0]);

            var index = 1;
            var result = new StringBuilder();
            while (brackets.Count > 0)
            {
                if (formula[index] == '(')
                    brackets.Push(formula[index]);
                else if (formula[index] == ')')
                    brackets.Pop();

                if (brackets.Count > 0)
                    result.Append(formula[index]);

                index++;
            }

            yield return new FunctionInfo((Function)Enum.Parse(typeof(Function), match.Value), result.ToString(), $"{match.Value}({result.ToString()})");

            formula = formula.Remove(0, result.Length + 2);
        }
        else
        {
            formula = formula.Remove(0, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Список функций известен? Их простым substring можно найти?

Comment: Да, список известен, про substring как раз думал. Просто интересно, есть ли другие решения. Например через регулярные выражения

Comment: Строго говоря, язык арифметических выражений не может быть разобран простым конечным автоматом. Для разбора требуется автомат с магазинной памятью (стеком). То есть ваша задача не решается регулярными выражениями. Однако, во многие движки регексов добавлены средства делающие их нерегулярными (но название осталось прежнее). В частности, в дотнете это [Balancing groups](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#balancing_group_definition) (Сбалансированные группы).

Comment: Но гораздо проще использовать, например, рекурсивный спуск. Примеров кода в интернете навалом на разных языках.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо, попробую реализовать алгоритм сортировочной станции, мне показалось, что он может подойти для моей задачи

Comment: [Вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1174507/373567) есть рекурсивный способ работы со скобками.