# Как интерпретировать математические символы строки в действие

Tags: c#, строки

Каким образом возможно выполнить действие с математическими операторами в строке после нажатия кнопки? К примеру пользователь вводит в переменную string типа следующий текст: "1 плюс 2" или "1 + 2". На выводе должно получиться "3" в обоих случаях после нажатия кнопки. Каким образом можно реализовать подобное? Я пытался написать функцию для каждого математического действия, а потом сделать поиск символа через цикл с последующим вызовом функции в теле if блока для каждого результата поиска, но у меня так и не вышло ничего, потому от этой идеи отказался. Как можно реализовать подобную задумку?

Comment: какие у вас операторы? всм только "+", или ещё "-", "*", ":"? и нужно ли вам учитывать приоритет операторов ("+" = "-" < "**" = "/")?

Comment: @return "+", "-", "*", "/", но вполне достаточно и одного примера. Желательно учитывать

Comment: в случае с плюсом просто аккумулируете сумму в переменную и затем парсите, добавляя значения (скоро будет ответ).

Comment: вы просто так галочками не раскидываетесь. в коде была ошибка. сейчас исправил.

Comment: ещё 1 фикс... да, я могу...

Comment: ключевые слова для гугления: синтаксический разбор, парсинг (не путать с парсингом сайтов), antlr

Comment: Не знаю, в тему или нет, но вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1174507/373567) еще пример для схожей задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool TryCompute(ReadOnlySpan<char> input, out int sum)
{
    sum = 0;
    var addend = 0;
    var state = ParserState.Digit;

    if (input.IsWhitespace()) return false;

    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        if (char.IsWhitespace(input[i]))
            continue;
        else if (input[i] >= '0' && input[i] <= '9')
        {
            if (state != ParserState.Digit) return false;

            var start = i;

            for (; i < input.Length && input[i] >= '0' && input[i] <= '9'; i++);

            var formattedAddend = input[start..i];

            if (!int.TryParse(formattedAddend, out addend)) return false;

            state = ParserState.Operator;

            i--;
        }
        else if (input[i] == '+')
        {
            if (state != ParserState.Operator) return false;

            sum += addend;

            state = ParserState.Digit;
        }
        else
            return false;

    if (state == ParserState.Digit) return false;

    sum += addend;

    return true;
}

enum ParserState
{
    Digit,
    Operator
}
```

Comment: добавь пример вызова еще. И не плохо было бы все-таки пояснение к коду :) Например, почему Span а не String

Comment: @Grundy вызов такой же как и для любого парсящего метода, `Span` потому что это .NET Core. по моему тут всё понятно. да и автор оставил галку, значит ему не нужны эти примитивные сюсюканья.

Comment: _Span потому что это .NET Core_ - а что, в net core - нет строк? :):):) Пояснения нужны не только автору, но и всем другим пользователям пришедшим в этот вопрос

Comment: @Grundy если что-то не понятно, пускай загуглят или спросят. тема этого вопроса — парсинг "1 + 11 + 54", `Span` — это совсем другие дебри. гуглите, если не нагуглили/не понятно — задавайте вопрос.

Comment: По приведенному коду - непонятно что гуглить :)  и непонятно как он работает.

Comment: @Grundy и как это должно выглядеть? `if (char.IsWhitespace(input[i]))` (комментарий: тут мы проверяем, является ли текущий символ пробелом), `state = ParserState.Digit` (комментарий: сейчас мы говорим, что парсим число, а не знак "+").

Comment: Это уж как ты хочешь :) Можешь просто алгоритм описать перед кодом, можешь каждую строчку прокомментировать, можешь указать используемые инструменты (классы) и т.д. вариантов масса