# Не могу реализовать вывод Resultat

Tags: c#

Есть код Калькулятора на Xamarin. Код разметки думаю не имеет смысла. Привожу код C#. Все работает, кроме вывода Result. Не могу понять, как его реализовать.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using static System.Double;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace AndroidCalculator
{
    [Activity(Label = "Android Calculator", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            Button button0 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button0);
            Button button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            Button button2 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
            Button button3 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button3);
            Button button4 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button4);
            Button button5 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button5);
            Button button6 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button6);
            Button button7 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button7);
            Button button8 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button8);
            Button button9 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button9);
            Button buttonMultiply = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonMultiply);
            Button buttonDivision = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonDivision);
            Button buttonSubtraction = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonSubtraction);
            Button buttonAddition = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonAddition);
            Button buttonResult = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonResult);
            Button buttonPoint = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonPoint);
            Button buttonClear = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonClear);
           

            EditText editTextOperate = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextOperate);
            TextView textViewResult = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewResult);

            buttonPoint.Click += delegate
            {
                if (editTextOperate.Text.Trim().EndsWith("."))
                {
                    editTextOperate.Text += "";
                }
                else if (editTextOperate.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
                {
                    editTextOperate.Text += ".";
                }
            };

            button1.Click += delegate
            {
                editTextOperate.Text += "1";
            };

            button2.Click += delegate
            {
                editTextOperate.Text += "2";
            };

            button3.Click += delegate
            {

                editTextOperate.Text += "3";
            };

            button4.Click += delegate
            {
                editTextOperate.Text += "4";
            };

            button5.Click += delegate
            {
                editTextOperate.Text += "5";
            };

            button6.Click += delegate
            {
                editTextOperate.Text += "6";
            };

            button7.Click += delegate
            {
                editTextOperate.Text += "7";
            };

            button8.Click += delegate
            {
                editTextOperate.Text += "8";
            };

            button9.Click += delegate
            {
                editTextOperate.Text += "9";
            };

            button0.Click += delegate
            {
                editTextOperate.Text += "0";
            };

            buttonAddition.Click += delegate
            {
                if (editTextOperate.Text.Length != 0)
                {
                    editTextOperate.Text += " + ";
                }
            };

            buttonSubtraction.Click += delegate
            {
                if (editTextOperate.Text.Length != 0)
                {
                    editTextOperate.Text += " - ";
                }
            };

            buttonMultiply.Click += delegate
            {
                if (editTextOperate.Text.Length != 0)
                {
                    editTextOperate.Text += " * ";
                }
            };

            buttonDivision.Click += delegate
            {
                if (editTextOperate.Text.Length != 0)
                {
                    editTextOperate.Text += " / ";
                }
            };

            Regex regex = new Regex(@"^-?\d*\.?\d*");

            buttonResult.Click += delegate
            {
                if (editTextOperate.Text != string.Empty & regex.IsMatch(editTextOperate.Text))
                {
                    double result = Math.Sqrt(Parse(editTextOperate.Text.Trim()));
                    textViewResult.Text = Convert.ToString(result, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                }
            };
           

            buttonClear.Click += delegate
            {
                ClearDisplay(editTextOperate, textViewResult);
            };

           
        }

        private void ClearDisplay(EditText editTextOperate, TextView textViewResult)
        {
            editTextOperate.Text = string.Empty;
            textViewResult.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Реализовал к примеру в Result вывод Sqrt от числа, все работает, а если например при сложении, умножении и тд, не могу сообразить

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1174507/373567

Comment: А чем мне это поможет?

Comment: Мне бы помогло.

Comment: А я не вы, по этому не понимаю, как мне поможет

Comment: Какой ответ вы ожидаете? У вас есть математическое выражение в строке, вам нужно его распарсить и посчитать его результат, я вам даю готовый код, который это делает, а вы меня спрашиваете "чем мне это поможет?". Это троллинг чтоли?

Comment: Вот еще https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266812/373567

Comment: Благодарю, все получилось, спасибо!