# Как превратить формулу в формате "string", с переменними которие уже есть в коде в виражение которое би поняла программа(например: a+b/c) (C#)

Tags: c#, парсер, eval, c#-8.0

Уже немало времени ищу в интернете как превратить формулу в формате "string", с переменными которые уже есть в коде в выражение которое би поняла и решила программа, например:

```
int a=2;
int b=4;
int c=2;
string s="a+b/c";
```

Если кто знает как это сделать без подключения библиотек, скажите, а если знаете хорошие библиотеки на этот счет тоже скажите.

Єто должно бить чтото вроде

```
 int r=Eval("a+b/c");
```

Comment: то есть, написать самому? это уже почти классическая задача. я тут раз месяц точно даю ссылку на https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8 - а в украинской версии даже есть примеры кода, которые легко адаптировать

Comment: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266812/373567), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1174507/373567)

Comment: Разделить на два массива чисел и знаков, после находить : и * после с помощью индексов заменять, например 4 + 5 / 2 - 2 на 4 + 2.5 - 2 (В массиве чисел, а в массиве знаков удалять знак)